# Unable to Pass Null Value in Json - MVC Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, null

System is not passing 'null' value if there is no value for

```
model.SpecialtyTypeDesc = spec.SpecialtyDescription;
```

I am unable to open the edit page if there is no value for Specialty for the employee. If the employee has specificity value, its working fine. I want to display the value as Null if the employee doestn't have any specialty in his personnel data.

```
public JsonResult GetSpecialityDepartment(int id){
    EmployeeDepartments getDep = (from c in db.EmployeeDepartments where c.EmpId == id select c).FirstOrDefault();
    Departments dept = (from c in db.Departments where c.Id == getDep.departmentId select c).FirstOrDefault();
    EmployeeDetails details = (from c in db.EmployeeDetails where c.People_Id == id select c).FirstOrDefault();
    SpecialtyType spec = (from c in db.SpecialityType where c.SpecialtyTypeId == details.SpecialtyTypeId select c).FirstOrDefault();
    var data = new { 
        Department = dept.Name,
        SpecialtyType = spec == null ? "" : spec.SpecialtyDescription
    };

    return Json(data);
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    PersonnelLeaveAbsence leaveAbsence = (from c in db.PersonnelLeaveAbsence where c.PersonnelLeaveAbsenceId == id select c).FirstOrDefault();
    EmployeeDepartments getDep = (from c in db.EmployeeDepartments where c.EmpId == leaveAbsence.PersonnelId select c).FirstOrDefault();
    Departments dept = (from c in db.Departments where c.Id == getDep.departmentId select c).FirstOrDefault();
    EmployeeDetails details = (from c in db.EmployeeDetails where c.People_Id == leaveAbsence.PersonnelId select c).FirstOrDefault();
    SpecialtyType spec = (from c in db.SpecialtyType where c.SpecialtyTypeId == details.SpecialtyTypeId select c).FirstOrDefault();

    PersonnelLeaveAbsenceModel model = new PersonnelLeaveAbsenceModel();
    model.PersonnelLeaveAbsenceId = leaveAbsence.PersonnelLeaveAbsenceId;
    model.PersonnelLeaveDate = leaveAbsence.LeaveDate;
    model.LeaveAbsenceId = leaveAbsence.LeaveAbsenceTypeId;
    model.PersonnelId = leaveAbsence.PersonnelId;
    model.EmployeeRoleId = leaveAbsence.EmployeeRole;
    model.StartTime = leaveAbsence.StartTime;
    model.EndTime = leaveAbsence.EndTime;
    model.DayType = Convert.ToBoolean(leaveAbsence.DayType);
    model.DepartmentDesc = dept.Name;
    model.SpecialtyTypeDesc = spec.SpecialtyDescription;
}
```

Comment: What do your means _is not passing 'null' value_? If its `nul`l then its `null`! If you mean you want to display the text "Null" if its `null`, then use the `[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="Null")]` attribute on the property or set the value to "Null"

Comment: If there is value specialty in orginal personnel table, its passing the value. If there is no value for specialty in orginal personnel table, the code stop at 'model.SpecialtyTypeDesc = spec.SpecialtyDescription;'. It suppose to display empty field. Thank yu.

Comment: Do you mean your getting an exception because `spec` is null?

Comment: Yes. Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Kind of important to include that in the question don't you think. Just test for null before assigning it `if (spec != null) { model.SpecialtyTypeDesc = spec.SpecialtyDescription; }`